# How could use SnackBars within the Scaffold in stateless widget?

Tags: flutter, snackbar

I have a class extends StatelessWidget. When try call SnackBars in Scaffold like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            splashRadius: 18,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
            tooltip: 'Like the app',
            onPressed: () {
              final SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                content: const Text('Registered as you like the application.'),
                action: SnackBarAction(
                  label: 'Undo',
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              );
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
            },
          ),
        ],
        title: const Text('My Application'),),
        body: const Center(
        child: Text("Hello World!"),)
        );
     }
 }
```

when run the application show error like:

> **Exception has occurred.**
> FlutterError (No ScaffoldMessenger widget found.
> MyApp widgets require a ScaffoldMessenger widget ancestor.
> The specific widget that could not find a ScaffoldMessenger ancestor was:
> MyApp
> The ancestors of this widget were:
> [root]
> Typically, the ScaffoldMessenger widget is introduced by the MaterialApp at the top of your application widget tree.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem but first: why the error happened?
It Fails because ScaffoldMessenger.of(context) doesn't find anything above this widget's context.
the solution to use Builder class as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            actions: <Widget>[

              Builder(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return IconButton(
                    splashRadius: 18,
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                    tooltip: 'Like the app',
                    onPressed: () {
                      final SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
                        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                        content: const Text(
                            'Registered as you like the application.'),
                        action: SnackBarAction(
                          label: 'Undo',
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      );
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
            title: const Text('My Application'),
          ),
          body: const Center(
            child: Text("Hello World!"),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your app in an `MaterialApp`, like

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
```

Comment: But: when Wrap scaffold with MaterialApp in the class MyApp, I get the same error..

Comment: @anasrokbi that's why I wrote it outside the class. It needs to be outside because otherwise you pass the wrong `context` to `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)`

Comment: I got it finally and use Builder class and solve it.. thank you..

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ScaffoldMessenger(
        key: key,
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  splashRadius: 18,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                  tooltip: 'Like the app',
                  onPressed: () {
                    final snackBar = SnackBar(
                      content: Text(
                        "message",
                        // style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.regularWhite14,
                      ),
                      duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
                      action: SnackBarAction(
                        label: 'OK',
                        textColor: CustomColorScheme.whiteColor,
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    );
                    key.currentState!.showSnackBar(snackBar);
                  },
                ),
              ],
              title: const Text('My Application'),
            ),
            body: const Center(
              child: Text("Hello World!"),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It works. but in StatefulWidget.. Can we do the same in StatelessWidget?? how?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from the youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lytQi-slT5Y) as the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
final _scaffoldkey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      scaffoldMessengerKey: _scaffoldkey,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              splashRadius: 18,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
              tooltip: 'Like the app',
              onPressed: () {
                final SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
                  duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                  content:
                      const Text('Registered as you like the application.'),
                  action: SnackBarAction(
                    label: 'Undo',
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                );
                ScaffoldMessengerState? scaffold = _scaffoldkey.currentState;
                scaffold!.showSnackBar(snackBar);
              },
            ),
          ],
          title: const Text('My Application'),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text("Hello World!"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```